# Parellize some nested for in openmp c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, openmp

My serial code for the convolution between a matrix and a kernel works like this:

```
int index1, index2, a, b;
for(int x=0;x<rows;++x){
    for(int y=0;y<columns;++y){
        for(int i=0;i<krows;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<kcolumns;++j){
                a=x+i-krows/2;  
                b=y+j-kcolumns/2;                   
                if(a<0)
                    index1=rows+a;
                else if(a>rows-1)
                    index1=a-rows;
                else 
                    index1=a;

                if(b<0)
                    index2=columns+b;
                else if(b>columns-1)
                    index2=b-columns;
                else 
                    index2=b;

                output[x*columns+y]+=input[index1*columns+index2]*kernel[i*kcolumns+j];

            }
        }

    }
}
```

The convolution considers cyclic treatment for the borders. Now I want to parallelize the code with openmp. I thought about reducing the first two for-cycles to just one and using the syntax:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for private(x,y,a, b, index1, index2)
for(int z=0;z<rows*columns;z++){
    x=z/columns;
    y=z%columns;
    ...
```

I see that parallelizing like that it reduces the cpu-time but I'm not a big expert of openmp so I was asking myself if there are other more efficient solutions. I don't think it is a good idea to parallelize also the others 2 nested for-cycles.
With an input matrix of dimensions 1000*10000 and a square kernel matrix 9*9 I obtain these times:

4823 ms for 1 thread

2696 ms for 2 threads

2513 ms for 4 threads.

I hope someone can give me some useful suggestions. What about the for reduction syntax?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  Recent openmp immplentations have loop collapse directive.  Also, declare your loop variables as you need them - it is much cleaner and variables declared inside the parallel region are automatically private.

Comment: Yes I know about the collapse directive but not really sure if my code will be tested in a compatible system. For the rest I know what you mean but these are not my issues. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just for an extra information, which CPU are you using?

Comment: I use an i5 with 1.70 Ghz but I do programming in a vmware virtual machine (in order to use linux). I set the number of processors to 4.

Comment: @user73793, if your system has two cores with hyper-treading then you're doing quite well already.  You can't expect a linear speed up beyond the number of physical cores.  Also, while it's fine to develop in a virtual machine (I do the same thing often) I would NOT do performance testing this way.  Install Visual Studio Express 2013 (it's free - in the free beer sense, not in the freedom sense) or dual boot into Linux.  Even then you will be testing two different implementations of OpenMP and I know from experience this can make a big difference as well.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to change approach altogether. If you are using cyclic treatment for the border (i.e. your problem is periodic) the fast way to do it is based on the fft-based spectral approach:

-Fourier transform matrix and kernel
-compute the product
-Inverse fourier transform the product (you have the convolution)

This is (1) much more efficient (unless the dimensions of the kernel are much smaller than those of the matrix) and (2) you can use a fft library that supports multithreading (like FFTW) and let it deal with it.

Comment: Well I think this solution requires a lot of work programming speaking and yes the kernels are much smaller than the input matrix so I don't think it worths.

Comment: @user73793 It does not take a lot of work at all in mere terms of lines of code, but if you are not at all familiar with fft's then it probably would take some effort to pin it down. If your kernel will always be a 9-by-9 I agree it is not worth it, because the complexity of your "direct" approach is already O(N) (N being the number of elements of the matrix). If in the future you may need to generalize to kernels which are not compactly supported, like a Gaussian kernel, I think it could be worth the investment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the for loops. You can make each thread iterate thru all rows in a column or thru all columns in a row. Also, bear in mind that if the number of threads is higher than the number of physical cores, the performance won't change much.

OpenMP already takes care of the number of threads that it should create, using the logical cores count - which might be a problem on Intel i3 and i7, since they have hyperthreading and thus the performance gain per extra thread won't be big.

In resume, you can either:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private (x,y,a,b,index1,index2)
for(int x=0;x<rows;++x){
    for(int y=0;y<columns;++y){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or:

```
for(int x=0;x<rows;++x){
    #pragma omp parallel for private (y,a,b,index1,index2)
    for(int y=0;y<columns;++y){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenMP 3.0 or greater you may exploit the `collapse` clause of the loop work-sharing construct:

> The collapse clause may be used to specify how many loops are
>   associated with the loop construct. The parameter of the collapse
>   clause must be a constant positive integer expression. If no collapse
>   clause is present, the only loop that is associated with the loop
>   construct is the one that immediately follows the loop directive

This means that you may write the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for(int x=0;x<rows;++x){
    for(int y=0;y<columns;++y){
        /* Work here */
    }
}
```

and obtain exactly the same result as your linearized loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
for(int z=0;z<rows*columns;z++){
    x=z/columns;
    y=z%columns;
    /* Work here */
}
```

As you may see, with the `collapse` clause  no modification is needed to your serial code and you may easily experiment further loop collapsing changing the positive number in the clause.

Comment: I always found fusing a loop so trivial that I did not really see the point of using `collapse`.  However, I guess the point is that if you compile without OpenMP then you get the original unfused code.  More generally, what big feature am I missing by only using OpenMP 2.0 except for tasks (reductions on min and max and atomic equality I can do myself)?

Comment: @Zboson I assume the point of collapse is exactly not modifying the initial un-fused loop (mainly for readability). Regarding the __big features__, I assume that you are missing tasks from 3.X and SIMD and offload directives from 4.0. I must admit though I did not have time yet to fully explore the latest standard, so I may be forgetting something...